# How to move SpriteKit Node as Car driving experience?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to move my car based on user touch but with curves. It's moving properly whenever I touch on the scene. But I need to move it with the perfect momentum of the car.

**1.** Touch anywhere in **Front**: It should move straight and stops when the user touched.

**2.** Touch anywhere in **Front Right**: It should move with a curve in turn right.

**3.** Touch anywhere in **Front Left**: It should move with a curve in turn Left.

**4.** Touch anywhere in **Bottom/Back**: It should move straight reverse.

**5.** Touch anywhere in **Bottom Right**: It should move reverse with a curve in turn right.

**6.** Touch anywhere in **Bottom Left**: It should move reverse with a curve in turn Left.

And it should behave the same even if it's rotated to horizontal as well.

I am new in SpriteKit so, Other solutions most welcome.

[Please check image for an idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTBFf.png)

[image]

Comment: HI Ajay and welcome to SO. Unfortunately your question isn't a good one as were not really sure what you are asking. You won't get 'real driving experience' from 'touches on the scene' as real driving needs analog input (a steering wheel etc). Can you add some diagrams to show what you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry about this, Let me elaborate it more.

Comment: @SteveIves please check the updated question and image hope it helps to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

What you’re going to have to do is to detect a touch on the sprite, work out where about on the sprite it is in relation to the centre and then move the sprite (maybe via an SKAction following your CGPath).

There’s quite a few different concepts involved so if you’re really new to Sprite Kit, I’d recommend some good SK tutorials. Personally I like the ones at raywenderlich.com but there are good ones on places like Udemy too.

Comment: Yes Thanks, Steve. I am currently doing with CGPath and SKAction to follow it but when I touch somewhere backside of the car it's directly rotated to back I want something like it should go reverse or another option is to turn smoothly and go.

Comment: So the car turns to face the touch? You have to maybe decide that if the touch is on the 'rear' half of the car, it reverses rather that rotates.

Comment: Yes, I am detecting that if a touched position is front or back but SKAction with follow path rotating car straight to back and then start moving so car not going in a reverse direction. So, after all, it seems like creating the path from the front what I can do to move a car in a reverse direction with a curve path.

Comment: When your create an action for a sprite to follow a CGPath, there's an option to have the sprite rotate to face the path. As it's back to front, the easiest solution may be to create the path in the reverse direction.

Comment: It sounds as though you've done more work on this that your question alludes to. If the problem of the car facing the wrong way is the only one you have, you should rephrase your question and include your code.

Comment: Yes, I have tried but I am looking for another approach as I am not sure with my current solution is the right way or not.